# npm install generates huge list of errors

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I must preface this question by saying that I am really new to Angular and Node.  Following the directions from [this Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391) tutorial, I cloned a sample Angular repo and then ran `npm install`. That yielded a massive list of errors, and then left my Terminal hanging for about 5 minutes. After that, I ran `npm start` and opened the sample app, which seemed to function just fine.

As I said, I'm very new to Angular and Node, so I don't know how to debug the errors I'm seeing, or if it's even something I should worry about. Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks!

`npm install` log: https://gist.github.com/danielbonnell/30959bd15297f1f4ab43

```
➜  angular-seed git:(master) npm install
npm WARN engine karma@0.10.10: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.5"})
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-jasmine@~0.1.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-requirejs@~0.2.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-coffee-preprocessor@~0.1.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-html2js-preprocessor@~0.1.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-chrome-launcher@~0.1.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-firefox-launcher@~0.1.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-phantomjs-launcher@~0.1.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma-script-launcher@~0.1.0 included from karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.

> fsevents@0.2.1 install /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:339:13: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return  _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
macro '_NAN_ERROR'n/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from -
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:348:9: error: no type named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    v8::ThrowException(error);
    ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:355:65: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    v8::Local<v8::Value> err = v8::Exception::Error(v8::String::New(msg));
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:357:26: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    obj->Set(v8::String::New("code"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:357:65: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
    obj->Set(v8::String::New("code"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~            ^
/Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2012:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Integer> New(Isolate* isolate, int32_t value);
  ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:369:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:377:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:727:49: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'isolate' was not specified
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Object::New();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2388:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Object> New(Isolate* isolate);
  ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:733:49: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'isolate' was not specified
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Object::New();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2388:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Object> New(Isolate* isolate);
  ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:740:12: error: no member named 'Dispose' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    handle.Dispose();
    ~~~~~~ ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:741:12: error: no member named 'Clear' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    handle.Clear();
    ~~~~~~ ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:746:39: error: no member named 'NewSymbol' in 'v8::String'; did you mean 'IsSymbol'?
    NanPersistentToLocal(handle)->Set(NanSymbol("callback"), fn);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:181:38: note: expanded from macro 'NanSymbol'
#define NanSymbol(value) v8::String::NewSymbol(value)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1379:8: note: 'IsSymbol' declared here
  bool IsSymbol() const;
       ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:746:39: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    NanPersistentToLocal(handle)->Set(NanSymbol("callback"), fn);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:181:38: note: expanded from macro 'NanSymbol'
#define NanSymbol(value) v8::String::NewSymbol(value)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.2.1

> ws@0.4.32 install /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency requirejs@~2.1 included from karma-requirejs will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
\
> phantomjs@1.9.16 install /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

PhantomJS detected, but wrong version 2.0.0 @ /usr/local/bin/phantomjs.
Downloading https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip
Saving to /var/folders/bq/g95dzyzn6nv074fpfhz2tjkh0000gn/T/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip
Receiving...
  [========================----------------] 60% 0.0s
Received 9187K total.
Extracting zip contents
Removing /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /var/folders/bq/g95dzyzn6nv074fpfhz2tjkh0000gn/T/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip-extract-1429227494807/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx -> /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/Dropbox/Launch_Academy/angular-seed
> bower install

bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0       not-cached git://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git#~4.3.0
bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0          resolve git://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git#~4.3.0
bower angular-route#1.2.x            not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.x
bower angular-route#1.2.x               resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.x
bower angular-loader#1.2.x           not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-loader.git#1.2.x
bower angular-loader#1.2.x              resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-loader.git#1.2.x
bower angular-mocks#~1.2.x           not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.2.x
bower angular-mocks#~1.2.x              resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.2.x
bower angular#1.2.x                  not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.x
bower angular#1.2.x                     resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.x
bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0         download https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/archive/v4.3.0.tar.gz
bower angular-mocks#~1.2.x             download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/archive/v1.2.28.tar.gz
bower angular#1.2.x                    download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.28.tar.gz
bower angular-route#1.2.x              download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route/archive/v1.2.28.tar.gz
bower angular-loader#1.2.x             download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-loader/archive/v1.2.28.tar.gz
bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0          extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-mocks#~1.2.x              extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-loader#1.2.x              extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-route#1.2.x               extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-mocks#~1.2.x             resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.28
bower angular#1.2.x                     extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-loader#1.2.x             resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-loader.git#1.2.28
bower angular-route#1.2.x              resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.28
bower angular#1.2.x                    resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0     invalid-meta html5-boilerplate is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0     invalid-meta html5-boilerplate is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0         resolved git://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git#4.3.0
bower angular-mocks#~1.2.x              install angular-mocks#1.2.28
bower angular-loader#1.2.x              install angular-loader#1.2.28
bower angular-route#1.2.x               install angular-route#1.2.28
bower angular#1.2.x                     install angular#1.2.28
bower html5-boilerplate#~4.3.0          install html5-boilerplate#4.3.0

angular-mocks#1.2.28 app/bower_components/angular-mocks
└── angular#1.2.28

angular-loader#1.2.28 app/bower_components/angular-loader
└── angular#1.2.28

angular-route#1.2.28 app/bower_components/angular-route
└── angular#1.2.28

angular#1.2.28 app/bower_components/angular

html5-boilerplate#4.3.0 app/bower_components/html5-boilerplate
karma-junit-reporter@0.2.2 node_modules/karma-junit-reporter
└── xmlbuilder@0.4.2

shelljs@0.2.6 node_modules/shelljs

http-server@0.6.1 node_modules/http-server
├── opener@1.3.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── portfinder@0.2.1 (mkdirp@0.0.7)
├── optimist@0.5.2 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
├── ecstatic@0.4.13 (ent@0.0.7, mime@1.2.11, optimist@0.3.7)
└── union@0.3.8 (pkginfo@0.2.3, qs@0.5.6)

protractor@1.8.0 node_modules/protractor
├── jasminewd@1.1.0
├── jasminewd2@0.0.2
├── saucelabs@0.1.1
├── html-entities@1.1.2
├── q@1.0.0
├── minijasminenode@1.1.1
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── source-map-support@0.2.10 (source-map@0.1.32)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── accessibility-developer-tools@2.6.0
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── request@2.36.0 (aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, qs@0.6.6, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.3, tough-cookie@0.12.1, form-data@0.1.4, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@1.0.0)
├── jasmine@2.1.1 (jasmine-core@2.1.3)
└── selenium-webdriver@2.44.0 (tmp@0.0.24, xml2js@0.4.4)

bower@1.4.1 node_modules/bower
├── is-root@1.0.0
├── junk@1.0.1
├── stringify-object@1.0.1
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── user-home@1.1.1
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── which@1.0.9
├── rimraf@2.3.2
├── archy@1.0.0
├── opn@1.0.1
├── bower-logger@0.2.2
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2
├── graceful-fs@3.0.6
├── lockfile@1.0.0
├── lru-cache@2.6.1
├── nopt@3.0.1
├── retry@0.6.1
├── tmp@0.0.24
├── q@1.2.0
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── shell-quote@1.4.3 (array-filter@0.0.1, array-map@0.0.0, array-reduce@0.0.0, jsonify@0.0.0)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (intersect@0.0.3, deep-extend@0.2.11, graceful-fs@2.0.3)
├── semver@2.3.2
├── fstream@1.0.4 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── p-throttler@0.1.1 (q@0.9.7)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── tar-fs@1.5.0 (pump@1.0.0, tar-stream@1.1.3)
├── fstream-ignore@1.0.2 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@2.0.4)
├── glob@4.5.3 (inherits@2.0.1, inflight@1.0.4, once@1.3.1, minimatch@2.0.4)
├── insight@0.5.3 (object-assign@2.0.0, lodash.debounce@3.0.3, async@0.9.0, os-name@1.0.3, tough-cookie@0.12.1)
├── update-notifier@0.3.2 (is-npm@1.0.0, string-length@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.0.0, latest-version@1.0.0)
├── decompress-zip@0.1.0 (mkpath@0.1.0, touch@0.0.3, readable-stream@1.1.13, binary@0.3.0)
├── github@0.2.3
├── bower-registry-client@0.3.0 (graceful-fs@2.0.3, request-replay@0.2.0, rimraf@2.2.8, lru-cache@2.3.1, async@0.2.10, mkdirp@0.3.5, request@2.51.0)
├── cardinal@0.4.4 (ansicolors@0.2.1, redeyed@0.4.4)
├── request@2.53.0 (caseless@0.9.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.6.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, isstream@0.1.2, qs@2.3.3, node-uuid@1.4.3, combined-stream@0.0.7, form-data@0.2.0, mime-types@2.0.10, bl@0.9.4, http-signature@0.10.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, hawk@2.3.1)
├── bower-config@0.6.1 (osenv@0.0.3, graceful-fs@2.0.3, optimist@0.6.1, mout@0.9.1)
├── mout@0.11.0
├── handlebars@2.0.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── configstore@0.3.2 (object-assign@2.0.0, xdg-basedir@1.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, uuid@2.0.1, js-yaml@3.2.7)
└── inquirer@0.8.0 (figures@1.3.5, ansi-regex@1.1.1, mute-stream@0.0.4, through@2.3.7, readline2@0.1.1, lodash@2.4.1, rx@2.5.2, cli-color@0.3.3, chalk@0.5.1)

karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.4 node_modules/karma-firefox-launcher

karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 node_modules/karma-script-launcher

karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 node_modules/karma-html2js-preprocessor

karma-jasmine@0.1.5 node_modules/karma-jasmine

karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.8 node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher
└── which@1.0.9

requirejs@2.1.17 node_modules/requirejs

karma-requirejs@0.2.2 node_modules/karma-requirejs

karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3 node_modules/karma-coffee-preprocessor
└── coffee-script@1.7.1 (mkdirp@0.3.5)

karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
└── phantomjs@1.9.16 (which@1.0.9, progress@1.1.8, kew@0.4.0, request-progress@0.3.1, adm-zip@0.4.4, npmconf@2.1.1, request@2.42.0, fs-extra@0.16.5)

karma@0.10.10 node_modules/karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@1.2.3
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── rimraf@2.1.4
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.6.1)
├── optimist@0.3.7 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
├── coffee-script@1.6.3
├── lodash@1.1.1
├── log4js@0.6.23 (async@0.2.10, underscore@1.8.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, semver@4.3.3)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (colors@0.6.2, pkginfo@0.3.0, optimist@0.6.1, utile@0.2.1)
├── chokidar@0.8.4 (recursive-readdir@0.0.2)
├── connect@2.8.8 (methods@0.0.1, uid2@0.0.2, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.1, qs@0.6.5, fresh@0.2.0, bytes@0.2.0, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, cookie@0.1.0, send@0.1.4, debug@2.1.3, formidable@1.0.14)
├── useragent@2.0.10 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
└── socket.io@0.9.17 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
```

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Karma 0.10 incompatible with node 0.12

> `npm WARN engine karma@0.10.10: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.5"})`

Switch to a node 0.10 version and the install will probably work.

Comment: Thanks! I installed `n` and switched to Node v0.10.38 and this time the install ran flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, the reason why got the errors is that your `Node.js` version does not match with `Angular.js`

```
karma@0.10.10: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.5"})
```

there is two way to fix your problem

1. Downgrade your Node.js version to match with Angular.js
2. Install `nvm` to switch your `Node.js` version

but i suggest you try the latter as it is an easy way to manage `Node.js` version using the `nvm`.

Answer (score 2):

> **wanted**: `{"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"}` (**current**: {`"node":"0.12.2"`,"npm":"2.7.5"})

As per message, you need to to downgrade your `node` package, since the package is not compatible with the newest `node`. This can be achieved by the following commands:

```
npm install -g n
n 0.10.44
node --version
```

<sup>The [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package interactively manages all your node versions.</sup>

To switch back to the latest, run: `n latest`.