# Getting this error when I run npm i or install, how do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting this error when I run npm i or install, I tried updating, I ran npm install node-sass, and npm update. Basically trying to get this environment running so I can do some work, lead dev isn't in so I have no one to ask.

```
Randolph-Wiafes-MacBook-Pro:plbg randy$ npm i
npm WARN engine email-templates@0.1.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x | 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})

> contextify@0.1.13 install /Users/randy/Desktop/plbg/node_modules/email-templates/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node: Finished

> node-sass@0.8.6 install /Users/randy/Desktop/plbg/node_modules/email-templates/node_modules/node-sass
> node build.js

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o
In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:339:13: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return  _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in
      namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:348:9: error: no type named 'ThrowException' in
      namespace 'v8'
    v8::ThrowException(error);
    ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:355:65: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    v8::Local<v8::Value> err = v8::Exception::Error(v8::String::New(msg));
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:357:26: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    obj->Set(v8::String::New("code"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:357:65: error: too few arguments to function call,
      expected 2, have 1
    obj->Set(v8::String::New("code"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~            ^
/Users/randy/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2012:3: note: 'New' declared
      here
  static Local<Integer> New(Isolate* isolate, int32_t value);
  ^
In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:369:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in
      namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:377:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in
      namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:727:49: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'isolate' was not specified
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Object::New();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/randy/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2388:3: note: 'New' declared
      here
  static Local<Object> New(Isolate* isolate);
  ^
In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:733:49: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'isolate' was not specified
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Object::New();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/randy/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2388:3: note: 'New' declared
      here
  static Local<Object> New(Isolate* isolate);
  ^
In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:740:12: error: no member named 'Dispose' in
      'v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    handle.Dispose();
    ~~~~~~ ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:741:12: error: no member named 'Clear' in
      'v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    handle.Clear();
    ~~~~~~ ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:746:39: error: no member named 'NewSymbol' in
      'v8::String'; did you mean 'IsSymbol'?
    NanPersistentToLocal(handle)->Set(NanSymbol("callback"), fn);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:181:38: note: expanded from macro 'NanSymbol'
#define NanSymbol(value) v8::String::NewSymbol(value)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/randy/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1379:8: note: 'IsSymbol'
      declared here
  bool IsSymbol() const;
       ^
In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:746:39: error: call to non-static member function
      without an object argument
    NanPersistentToLocal(handle)->Set(NanSymbol("callback"), fn);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:181:38: note: expanded from macro 'NanSymbol'
#define NanSymbol(value) v8::String::NewSymbol(value)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/randy/Desktop/plbg/node_modules/email-templates/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@0.8.6 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@0.8.6 install script 'node build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/randy/Desktop/plbg/npm-debug.log
```

Here is the link if you would like to visit the gist instead. Thank you guys for the help! https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wiafe/158589ec560cc051ca02/raw/45ec1ab53bf86f5b0289dc7098a7f317581d248e/gistfile1.txt

This is my node-debug.log file https://gist.github.com/wiafe/fb10d0e576e3a3e73b02

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install generates huge list of errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687917/npm-install-generates-huge-list-of-errors)

Answer (score 2):

> email-templates@0.1.8: `wanted: {"node":"0.8.x | 0.10.x"}` (`current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"}`)

You need to install older `node`, since the package is not compatible with the newest installed `node`. This can be achieved by installing `n` which can interactively manage all your node versions:

```
npm install -g n
```

then install it via:

```
n 0.10.44
```

Then check the current version:

```
$ node --version
v0.10.44
```

and install the package again.

To change back to the latest, run: `n latest`.

Comment: You must provide the full command in each statement

Answer (score 1):

This package "email-templates" isn't compatible with node 0.12. Try switching to node 0.10.

Comment: Do I do that with npm?